# Missing icon in app-launcher

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu

In my app-launcher ( Kubuntu 20.04.2 ) I am missing some icons. For example the icon for Kmahjongg. When I look in properties I can see the icon (/usr/share/icons/breeze/apps/48/Kmahjongg.svg), but not in the app-launcher. See picture.[image]
 Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some time to search for the icons. There were 3, located in different places. The one that worked was located in `var/lib/app-info/ubuntu-focal-universe/48x48`.
Beautyful, as it should be.